# in App purchase | in App billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am working on in-app-billing from my android phone. I am signed in with my google account and i can buy any in-app items (from other apps like games etc). But, when I tried to use in my app it is not working...getting error "Authentication is required. you need to sign into your Google Account."

For other application it is working but not for me. What do I need to do here? Log I received:

```
D/IabHelper: Starting in-app billing setup.
D/IabHelper: Billing service connected.
D/IabHelper: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
D/IabHelper: In-app billing version 3 supported for 
D/IabHelper: Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
D/IabHelper: Starting async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
D/IabHelper: Constructing buy intent for com.example.purchased, item type: subs
D/IabHelper: Launching buy intent for com.example.purchased. Request code: 10001
```

Comment: This tutorial might help you: [link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-in-app-purchase-version-3)

Comment: thanks nougat lover, can u please tell me, what is SKU_SUBSCRIBED, SKU_PREMIUM, SKU_COINS  "Purchase subscriptionForFullVersion = inventory
.getPurchase(SKU_SUBSCRIBED)"
i am working for subscribe items

Comment: Those are the unique Identifiers you add during listing of your items to be sold on In-App purchase page

Comment: u mean product id?

Comment: That's Right...

Comment: still un solved :( getting purchase null

Comment: Can you post relevant code? Also, please explain, what do you mean by purchase null?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have downloaded your app from Google Play. If you run your app in debug mode and try to purchase, you will get authentication problems.

Comment: oh man! thanks @han.. actually  i tell what i did, 1) on google console i create account get base64encoded key set in my app and then upload apk to alpha 2) add tester my emailID and make user enable 3) add products and set active thats it.. now guide me if em wrong, should i need to publish my app? i dont think so, i tried above mention steps many time but getting same error "Authentication is required. you need to sign into your Google Account."

Comment: Please make sure the account you have been using is granted test permission. The problem might be with the accounts. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/getting-authentication-is-required-when-trying-to-access-the-play-store

Comment: checked @han, my app is not showing no app store.. how do i get that. it become a worst for me.